# How to calculate average of each column excluding first two rows

Tags: vba, excel, average

I tried to calculate average of every other columns excluding every first two rows.
Because there are letters in first two rows, they cause error.
I think I need to change `sh1.Columns(col)` this part to exclude first two rows.
Please give me some idea.

Thank you

```
Sub average()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet

Set sh1 = Sheets("combined")
Set sh2 = Sheets("avg")

Dim col As Long, row As Long

sh2.Cells.ClearContents

col = 4

Dim size As Long

'size = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
'size = sh1.Range(

sh2.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Average return"


'its from "parameter" sheet
For i = 1 To (42 - 11 + 1)

    'error caused by first two rows which include letters
     sh2.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Application.average(Columns(col))

     col = col + 2

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This has too much to optimize, worksheetfunction.average is asking you for a range, you are calculating the average fo the whole column wich is only necesary if all your rows contains values wich in most cases wont. raplace sh1.column(col) for a more specific range. for example range(cells(10,col),cells(1000,col)). this will only do the average from cell row=10 column=col to cell row=1000 column=col. so if you do it this way now you can speficify that it will start at certain row, in this case 10.

Comment: Thankss for the reply. I replace sh1.column(col) to sh1.Range(Cells(3, col), Cells(1008, col)) but I still get an error and this time it does not print out anything.

Comment: Use `sh1.Cells(3, col).Resize(1008,1)` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Application.Average` can fix this. Quick and dirty solution below.

My set-up:

[image]

Code (very dirty, modify as necessary):

```
Sub Ave()
    For i = 1 To 7 Step 2
    Columns(i).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Application.Average(Columns(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

EDIT:

Try the following code as per your specs.

```
Sub Avg()

    Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim tRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set Sh1 = .Sheets("combined")
        Set Sh2 = .Sheets("avg")
    End With

    With Sh2
        .Cells.ClearContents
        .Range("A1").Value = "Average return"
    End With

    tRow = 2

    For i = 4 To 66 Step 2
        Sh2.Range("A" & tRow).Value = Application.average(Sh1.Columns(i))
        tRow = tRow + 1
    Next i

End Sub
```

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The data structure you showed is just like what I have. But if I put Application.Average(Columns(i)) I got #DIV/0! for all results

Comment: (1) Are our data set similar? (2) Did you copy the code as is?

Comment: Data set is almost the same. The only difference is that I'm trying to printout average in other sheet(sh2).
And I just put 
(original left hand side) = application.average(columns(col))

Comment: @user3067818: "Almost" is a very difficult word when it comes to programming. ;) Please modify your post above and include there the names of your sheets and/or your complete code. If much of it is irrelevant, just edit them out and leave the name of the sheets as well as your declarations. This should be enough for us to work on.

Comment: ok I just add my whole code. col starts from 4 because columns 1~3 are not used to calculate average

Comment: @user3067818: Quite some dirty code. ;) Let me get this correctly: You are getting the average of values grouped by columns in `sh1` and printing them vertically in column A of `sh2`? How many columns of data do you have in `sh1` **OR** what is your last column in `sh1`?

Comment: yes I try to get the averages in sh1 and print them in column A of sh2
my last column is BN so there are 66 columns

Comment: It just shows the same results #DIV/0!. I really appreciate your replies though.

Comment: @user3067818: Did you copy as is the above? Try one more time, then try changing `Application.Average` with `WorksheetFunction.Average`. I'm thinking the reason why it didn't originally work is because `Columns(i)` was unqualified. I've added `Sh1.Columns(i)` so that it will surely take from `Sh1` the values. ;)

Comment: It works perfectly!! Thank you very much :)
I really want to vote but I do not have enough reputations for that...

Comment: @user3067818: That's alright. Glad it worked. Thanks for accepting. :)